# String comparison is wrong

Tags: java, string, equals

I have a little/huge problem with String comparison in Java, I want to compare two Strings and `.equals([...])` does not give me the correct result.

I also tried the following: `==`, `.compareTo([...])`, `.trim()`, `.equalsIgnoreCase([...])`, creating a Collator with default Locale and using `[collator].compare`.
(All fail to work)

The first String comes from an already created object (the content of the string is from a database), the second String comes from a newly created object (but has been passed to a method), the content of this String is from the same database.

I am pretty clueless what to do now, the last thing I'd try is to convert it to some number (i.e. hex).

I already tried to write both Strings to console and manually look for differences, but there is none...

Code is this:

```
    public static Lagerplatz hinzufuegen(Lagerplatz lagerplatz) {
    boolean neu = true;

    if (lagerplaetze.isEmpty()) {
        lagerplaetze.add(lagerplatz);
        System.out.println(lagerplatz.getBezeichnung() + " erstmalig hinzugefügt!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lagerplaetze.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("'" + lagerplatz.getBezeichnung() + "'" + " - " + "'"
                + lagerplaetze.get(i).getBezeichnung() + "'");
        if (lagerplatz.getBezeichnung().equalsIgnoreCase(lagerplaetze.get(i).getBezeichnung())) {
            neu = false;
        }
    }

    if (neu) {
        lagerplaetze.add(lagerplatz);
        System.out.println(lagerplatz.getBezeichnung() + " hinzugefügt!");
    }
    return lagerplatz;
}
```

The if-part with (lagerplaetze.isEmpty()) does work, after the first one is added it should check if the Lagerplatz (at least the name of it) is already in the lagerplaetze-ArrayList, if so then don't add, if not add.

Stepping through it revealed that the objects are correctly referenced...

Thanks very much in advance, and sorry if this question has been answered already but I can't find a helping answer under all these questions...

**EDIT1**: Normalizing does not help in this case, "umlaute" (german ä, ö or ü) are not causing the problem...

Converting the String to a byte[] and converting this byte-array to String like:

```
(Arrays.toString(lagerplatz.getBezeichnung().getBytes()).equalsIgnoreCase(
                Arrays.toString(lagerplaetze.get(i).getBezeichnung().getBytes())))
```

and then comparing it does also not solve the problem, the bytes of the two strings are exactly the same: `'[72, 55, 48]' - '[72, 55, 48]'`

**EDIT2**: The problem is not with the String comparison, it is because the variables of the class "Lagerplatz" are static, they were replaced each time the loop is entered...
Maybe delete this question?

Comment: You can try to print the actual bytes of each string by using `Arrays.toString( str.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_16)))`

Comment: what does getBezeichnung return? Code please.

Comment: You should be able to optimize things a little by returning `lagerplatz` from the bottom of the first `if`, and by adding a `break` after setting `neu` to `false`.

Comment: I can't get why that `isEmpty()` condition is actually needed ?  at the end, the argument is being added to the list anyhow :/

Comment: As this seems to be German strings, do we have an umlaut problem, i.e. an encoding problem the one string is ISO-8859-1 and the other is UTF-8 for instance?

Comment: And there definitely isn't whitespace at the beginning or end of one of the strings?

Comment: Don't you need to use 64bit java, and enable long string support for comparison of German strings to succeed?        www.bonkersworld.net/images/2014.11.11_german_scrabble.png

Comment: @Poldie never ever! Proof since JDK 1.4 ...

Comment: @MightyPork I sadly won't develop this all the time so I have to make sure that my successor will understand the entire program, I don't like it as well...

@X-Fate `getBezeichung(){ return bezeichnung; }` bezeichnung is a String.

@dasblinkenlight thank you, I didn't care for optimizing yet because it does not work :)

@mangusta I need it, otherwise the for-loop is never entered...

@AxelAmthor sadly this is not the problem, I made sure it is not before I asked the question :(

@starf there are whitespaces in the database entry but they are removed after `.trim()` is used...

Comment: See EDIT2 in my question. Just realized it when posting the comment below on hendriks answer...

Comment: You have the power to delete your own question... There are links under it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried, but I can't as it has an answer, I'd need to flag it for moderator attention,

Comment: @shagrinar precisely to make it easier to understand for your successors, it is a very bad idea not to use English. But whatever, it's your project, you'll receive the ire.

Answer (score 4):

The only time two strings that look *exactly* the same but `equals()` does not result in `true` is when the unicode composition is different.

For example one can compose the A umlaut (Ä) with a single character: `\u00C4`
Or with a combination of the `A` character and the dots (the dieresis character `¨`): `\u0041\u0308`

In essence, you are using *two* unicode characters for *one* letter. Because `equals()` compares characters, the form with dieresis is not equals to the form without.

To overcome this problem, one must decompose each string to a canonical form before comparison.

In Java one can create such a canonical form like this:

```
java.text.Normalizer.normalize("Your String", java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

Once normalized, `equals()` will work as expected.

Obviously, since you didn't provide any data, this answer may or may not match your problem.
In any case, you might want to normalize all Strings in some form and then use a `Set` as data structure, not a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer hendrik!
I normalized all Strings, sadly this did not work...

`String[] strLadungstraeger = Normalizer.normalize(rstImport.getString("txtItem").trim(),
     Normalizer.Form.NFD).split("#");
   String strLagerplatz = Normalizer.normalize(rstImport.getString("txtLagerplatz").trim(),
     Normalizer.Form.NFD);`

**Some data:**
`10 erstmalig hinzugefügt!`
`'10' - '10'`
`'1001' - '1001'`
`'H70' - 'H70'`
`'BL_Nord_1' - 'BL_Nord_1'` <--- SAME AS BELOW
`'BL_Nord_1' - 'BL_Nord_1'` <--- SAME AS ABOVE

Comment: See EDIT2 in my question. Just realized it when posting the comment above...